# Joomla 1.7 JRequest in k2 search plugin

Tags: search, plugins, joomla1.7, joomla-k2

I'm working in some 'advanced search' improvements in j1.7 with k2 v2.5.4

I'd like to request some parameters with JRequest::getInt() in file \plugins\search\k2\k2.php
but it seems to not reach this plugin.

Please how can I get some POST/GET new parameters?

thanks in advice

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this at the top of your code -

```
jimport( 'joomla.environment.request' );
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! I've used other method to do what I wanted, but this will stay for someone who need it.